# arreglo de pares y primos Javascript

Tags: javascript, números-primos

Tengo un arreglo de n cantindad de elementos en este caso puse del 1 al 10, pero pueden ser mas o inclusive random, el algoritmo tiene que guardar en 4 arreglos diferentes si el numero es par o impar, ademas de que si este es primo o no es primo. Por la parte del numero par o impar ya lo logre, pero la parte de primo o no aun no he podido completarla, cuando imprime el array de primos, me aparece el mismo array pero el doble, es decir [2,2,3,3,....]

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
let pares = [];
let impares = [];
let primos = [];
let noprimos = [];
for(let i= 0;i<array.length;i++){
    if(i % 2 ==0){
        pares.push(array[i]);
    }
    else{
        impares.push(array[i]);
    }
    for (let j = 2; j < array[i]; j++) {
        if (array[i] % j == 0) {
            noprimos.push(array[i]);
        }
        else{
            primos.push(array[i]);
        }
}
}

console.log("Los numeros pares son " + pares);
console.log("Los numeros impares son " + impares);
console.log("Los numeros primos son " + primos);
console.log("Los numeros NO primos son " + noprimos);
```

Comment: tengo una duda quería saber como podría hacerlo con una mesa de ordenarlos por columnas por docenas por color rojo y negros pares en impares [![mesa de casino con animalitos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8bqD.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8bqD.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuando con la logica que planteates se puede hacer lo siguiente:
Ojo: para evitar que se repitan los ciclos para cada numero se define antes la variable que controlara el ciclo que determina si es primo o no.

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
let pares = [];
let impares = [];
let primos = [];
let noprimos = [];
let j=1;
for(let i= 0;i<array.length;i++){
    if(i % 2 ==0){
        impares.push(array[i]);
    }
    else{
        pares.push(array[i]);
    }
    
      for (j; j < array.length; j++) {

      if (primo(array[j])) {
         primos.push(array[j]);
      }else{
         noprimos.push(array[j]);
      }
  
}

}

function primo(numero) {

  for (var i = 2; i < numero; i++) {

    if (numero % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }

  }

  return numero !== 1;
}

console.log("Los numeros pares son " + pares);
console.log("Los numeros impares son " + impares);
console.log("Los numeros primos son " + primos);
console.log("Los numeros NO primos son " + noprimos);
```

Answer (score 2):

El algoritmo que debes usar es una Criba. La solución puede ser esta para los primos y los no primos:

```js
   const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    const prime = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    let primos = [];
    let noprimos = [];
    for (let i = 2; i < array.length; i++) {
      if ( !prime[i] ) {
        primos.push(i);
        for ( let j = i * i; j < array.length; j += i ) {
          prime[j] = 1;
        }
      } else {
        noprimos.push(i);
      }
    }
    console.log("Los numeros primos son " + primos);
    console.log("Los numeros NO primos son " + noprimos);
```

Puedes chequear la documentación de la criba aqui:
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criba_de_Erat%C3%B3stenes

Si quieres algo más genérico puedes hacer esto

```
    const MAX = 100; // número máximo que quieres alcanzar
    const prime = [];
    for ( let i = 0; i < MAX; i++ ) {
      prime.push(0);
    }
    let primos = [];
    let noprimos = [];
    for (let i = 2; i < MAX; i++) {
      if ( !prime[i] ) {
        primos.push(i);
        for ( let j = i * i; j < MAX; j += i ) {
          prime[j] = 1;
        }
      } else {
        noprimos.push(i);
      }
    }
    console.log('Los numeros primos son ' + primos);
    console.log('Los numeros NO primos son ' + noprimos);
```